# Композитный объект в виде строки в plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plsql, sql

Например, если у меня есть массив интов, то в виде строки я могу передать в `plpgsql`-функцию фактическое значение аргумента `p_arg` в виде строки

```
"{77,55,33}"
```

и теперь если использовать в функции аргумент `p_arg[1]`, то там будет 77.
Теперь я в аргументе `p_person` передаю тип `person`, где есть, например поля `name`, `age`. Вроде пишут в мануале что-то вроде

```
("Vasya",33)
```

и тогда в `p_person.name` должно храниться 'Vasya', а в `p_person.age 33`, но когда передаю строку в таком формате вылетает ошибка "`ERROR:  malformed record literal:`". У кого есть опыт? Как это работает? (речь идет о СУБД `postgresql` )

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос. Чтобы записать массив структур, надо заэкранировать кавычки в содержимом элементов.Как в примере.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TYPE poligon.mytp AS (id INTEGER,name TEXT,born DATE);
/*массив будет выглядеть так и начинаться с 1
(1,"адын","2013-11-01"),
(2,"адын плус адын","2013-11-01"),
(3,"тры","2013-11-01")
*/
-- получим имя из второго элемента
SELECT  ('{"(\"1\",\"адын\",\"2013-11-01\")","(\"2\",\"адын плус адын\",\"2013-11-01\")","(\"3\",\"тры\",\"2013-11-01\")"}'::poligon.mytp[])[2].name;
```

По аналогии и в функциях pl\pgsql так же.